# My buffered reader for minecraft only reads the last line

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to create a buffered reader that makes a speech through chat with the intent of making saying long statements much easier.  I have this buffered reader hear, it works for the most part BUT it only reads the last line, everything else works perfectly fine.  Where in the code did I go wrong? For reference here it is: (for clarification, "eggtime" is a time delayed boolean)

> static File waffles = new File(Minecraft.getMinecraftDir(), "speech.txt");

```
public static void speechedo(String args)
{


    if(waffles.exists())
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        BufferedReader read = null;
        try {
            read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(waffles));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String notataco;
        if (eggtime){
        try {
            for(int i = 0; (notataco = read.readLine()) != null; i++)
            {

                speechmakerchat = notataco;


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    }else{
        return;}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
 speechmakerchat = notataco;
```

you are replacing the content of `speechmakerchat` with the last line, discarding the previously read value. You need to concatenate the new data to the old:

```
 speechmakerchat += notataco;
```

By the way, you have... interesting... naming conventions for your variables.

Comment: When I do that it jams the whole file into one line, speechmakerchat is a string that tells the client what to say in chat, when I tried this it gave me an error saying chat message too long.  How would I get it to read one line at a time, and go to the next line once triggered again?

Comment: sorry, but to answer that question I would need to know more about the API around it.

Comment: Text or the raw code itself?
I can tell you this in text, speechmakerchat is a string, whatever is in this string is sent through chat via a tick based delay that activates once every 180 ticks, when these 180 ticks occur it toggles a boolean that sends the set string as a chat message.

Comment: Is there some way to run code every tick? You could store all the lines returned from the BufferedReader in a List. Then you count the ticks and all 180 ticks you place the first element of the list in speechmakerchat and remove that element from the list.

Comment: Well, I managed to get the code to run every tick, I'm very very new with modding minecraft and not too experienced in coding java itself, I tried to create an array list and read through an iterator, but that just drew blank, so I got it to run every tick, the problem is brand new though, now it only reads the first line.

Comment: Do you again read the file every tick? The idea was to read the file into a list in one place (executed once) and do the output to the chat in another (executed every 180 ticks).

Answer (score 0):

> My buffered reader for minecraft only reads the last line

No, your buffered reader reads every line. However you are throwing away all but the last line.

Also your exception handling is poor. You shouldn't allow the method to continue after an IOException constructing the BufferedReader. Mostly your catch blocks are in the wrong place: they should be after all the main code.